# Spring autowiring failed but application starts up

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, autowired

Recently i faced a situation where a spring based application was throwing "NullPointerApplication" while accessing an autowired field in a Class ( A ). The bean being autowired is used in other classes ( B and C ) as well. Those classes ( B and C ) are working fine while accessing that bean.

```
applicaton-context.xml:

<bean id="myBean" class="x.y.x.MyBean">
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z" />


Class MyBean{
public void m(){
}
}

@Component    
Class A{

@Autowired
MyBean theBean;

public void methodA(){
  theBean.m();                       //Getting NPE
}

}

@Component
Class B{

@Autowired
MyBean theBean;

public void methodB(){
  theBean.m();                             // No NPEs, works fine
}

}

@Component
Class C{

@Autowired
MyBean theBean;

public void methodC(){
  theBean.m();                             // No NPEs, works fine
}

}
```

When i restarted the application everything is working fine. Earlier, If the bean autowiring failed Class A bean creation should fail and the application should not startup. On the contrary the application is working fine (except Class A) and no unable-to-autowire exception could be found. So I wonder if this is a rare-random case where Spring autowiring gets messed up ??? I am is correct in that? is this a known issue with Spring ?

Comment: Was this on a full restart or was the code hotdeployed?

Comment: Can you post the xml config where autowiring and component scanning is enabled?

Comment: I have edited the question, the application uses component-scan.  And yes it was a full restart, no code change was done .

Comment: Would methodA be called by any Spring initialization code(directly or indirectly)? Such as: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html

Comment: No, no bean initialization uses methodA

Comment: I guess you'll have to chalk it up to some random concurrency issue.  You're correct that context initialization should, and does, fail if an autowire fails to find a match.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your class A itself is in Spring context? Perhaps your classes B and C are autoscanned but not your class A (not in the base package of your component-scan).

In this case autowiring is just ignored in A, so your `theBean` instance is null.

Comment: No all the classes are autoscanned. I have this application for almost 2 years and never had this issue. Autowiring was happening fine earlier and after restart. Just during one startup i had this issue.